# Applying Textures in Three.js using a URL

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I'm having trouble applying textures in Three.js. I haven't been able to use any local images for this in Chrome because of security issues, so I'd like to apply an image from the web instead. Is there a way to map an image to a Three.js mesh using a URL?

Comment: [TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader) works with URLs

Answer (score 4):

TextureLoader does work with urls, just make sure that you set crossOrigin it loading urls not from your site's server. Here's an example:

```
const myUrl = 'http://www.myimage.com'

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
textureLoader.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"
const myTexture = textureLoader.load(myUrl)

myMesh.material.map(myTexture)
myMesh.material.needsUpdate = true
```

Comment: `TextureLoader()` sets the `needsUpdate` flag for you. Do not set it yourself; you may be setting it before the asynchronous loading of the texture completes.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Works great.